# Getting Chrome ( on mac ) to ask me whether it should save the login info

Tags: google-chrome

Somehow, at some point, I must have chosen the 'NEVER' option when Chrome asked me whether I should allow it to save/remember the uid/pwd info so next time I visit this web site, it pre-populates the uid and pwd for me. Because of my bloody choice at that time, I end up entering my login info all the time for certain web sites.

Is there anyway to tell Chrome, "Hey I'm sorry man! Ask me again, this time I will accept it!

Comment: This is not a programming question (it's a "how do I use Chrome" question), and therefore is off-topic here. This belongs on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the **Preferences** of Chrome, on mac just click **Chrome** in the upper left of your screen, and prolly something similar in windows.  Then go to **Settings**, at the bottom **Advanced Settings**, under **Passwords and Froms** make sure **Offer to save passwords I enter on the web** is checked and you can also **manage your passwords** there too.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what OS you are using Chrome on. On OSX, under Preferences, there's an Show Advanced Settings options, and that displays the 'Offer to save passwords I enter on the web' option. Enabling the checkbox should do it.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I edited the question title to include the OS.

Comment: You got it Specksynder. Right where you describe it, there is an option called "Manage saved passwords". There you see the ones where you accidentally ( or purposely picked to NEVER SAVE ). Deleting the site in subject does the trick! Stackoverflow rocked again!